# What is the Most reliable way to get Home Folders Paths using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I Have been using the below code, was working fine for 2 days but suddenly today i'm getting the error "Path is not found" .... annoying ...

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sf
Set sf = FSO.GetFolder(Environ("HOMEPATH")).Subfolders
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I Solved it already:

```
Environ("HOMEDRIVE") & Environ("HOMEPATH")
```